# AlexNet paper does not match dimensions they reported?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am following the [paper where AlexNet was introduced](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf), and the dimensions they report just don't match with the figure they attached.

The output of the first conv layer (which is 96 11x11x3 convolution) is 55x55x96 (for simple 1GPU case). Now the paper states that the second conv layer is applied to the output of a maxpooling layer. Assuming the MaxPool is a kernel of 3x3 with stride of 2 (as they report with s and z), this means that the input to the second convolution layer should be (55 - 3)/2 + 1 = 27 but in the picture provided for the AlexNet they write there is a Max Pooling operation there but they don't perform the dimension reduction of the pooling!

So the second conv layer should have been applied to a volumen with widht and height = 27 and not 55 right?

[image]

Furthermore, I took a look at how PyTorch was implementing it to see if I was missing something and they just changed the configuration, starting with 64 kernels... :

```
AlexNet(
  (features): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(11, 11), stride=(4, 4), padding=(2, 2))
    (1): ReLU(inplace)
    (2): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (3): Conv2d(64, 192, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 2))
    (4): ReLU(inplace)
    (5): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (6): Conv2d(192, 384, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (7): ReLU(inplace)
    (8): Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (9): ReLU(inplace)
    (10): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace)
    (12): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Dropout(p=0.5)
    (1): Linear(in_features=9216, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (2): ReLU(inplace)
    (3): Dropout(p=0.5)
    (4): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (5): ReLU(inplace)
    (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True)
  )
)
```

Comment: I can clearly see the 27x27x128 dimensions on the Conv2 layer; I do not see a 55x55 feeding another 55x55 on the diagram.  Where are the two of us out of synch?

Comment: As for the 64, yes, it appears to me as if the model engineer changed the topology width for those layers, and I don't see why.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [comment in a GitHub issue](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/pull/463#issuecomment-379214941) that explained this well:

> current implementation comes from [the torch re-implementation](https://github.com/soumith/imagenet-multiGPU.torch/blob/master/models/alexnetowt.lua), which is based on the [single GPU implementation from Alex](https://github.com/akrizhevsky/cuda-convnet2/blob/master/layers/layers-imagenet-1gpu.cfg#L81) which uses 256 filters, while the [2GPU implementation from Krizhevsky uses 384 filters](https://github.com/akrizhevsky/cuda-convnet2/blob/master/layers/layers-imagenet-2gpu-model.cfg#L163-L189).

The original AlexNet model needed to be trained across 2 GTX 580 3GB GPUs because the model was too large to be trained on a single GPU (at the time). Krizhevsky (the author of the paper) released a single GPU implementation with different dimensions and the PyTorch implementation comes from there.